# Updating git repo name

Tags: git

I just changed the name of my github repo and now my local repo (as expected) can't find it. How do I update the name, or am I just supposed to treat it as a new remote repo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From how I read this my understanding is that you changed the name of your repository (which changed the URL for it) and now you want to update the URL to match the new repository location.

You can use `git remote set-url <remote-name> <new-url>` to switch the URL for an existing remote repo.